# Could Whales Elsewhere be Afrotheres?

Tags: biology, evolution, anatomy

[image]

The largest animals alive today--and to loom into the human imagination--are the whales, a group of mammals that had been going from skinny-dip to full-blown dive in just 53.5 million years.  Due to their alien, almost non-mammalian shapes, you'd be surprised at which order they belong to.

[image]

Whales belong to the order **Artiodactyla**, the Even-Toed Ungulates.  The order is also exclusive to hippos, deer, camels, giraffes, pronghorns, antelopes, cattle, sheep, goats, pigs and peccaries.  (The differences between each other are so great that you would never notice that fact.)

But in an alternate Earth, the whales belong to another group:

[image]

### Afrotheria

Recent molecular evidence has found that this superorder is exclusive to elephants, sengis, aardvarks, tenrecs, hyraxes and sea cows.  But the connection, as far as I know, is strictly genetic, not visible to the naked eye or the process of fossilization.

In order for the whales of this alternate Earth to evolve from ancient afrotheres, should anything in their skeleton change shape and/or size to confirm that connection, or would the differences be strictly genetic?

Comment: The animal in the lower right corner of the picture of various Afrotheria makes for a convincing whale. It even has a fluke.

Comment: Consider that the shapes of whales are almost entirely the product of evolution for hydrodynamic optimization.  Dolphins & orcas look a awful lot like ichthyosaurs, which look quite a bit like sharks & tuna.  So unless your marine afrotheres get started down a completely different path (e.g. plesiosaur-like) they'll wind up with a strong external resemblance to cetacians.

Comment: @AlexP it is the beautiful , majestic, manatee

Comment: @XandarTheZenon: I know it's the manatee: but doesn't it look like it could play the part of the whale in a Hollywood movie? After all, didn't Anthony Quinn make a great Zorba the Greek?

Comment: @AlexP Sh,  (places finger over your mouth), they've done worse. Don't give them any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Whales would not be any different

There are no morphological features that distinguish the Afrotheres from other mammalian clades. There are also no common morphological features that united Cetacea with Artiodactyls, even though the two have a common ancestor. The Cetaceans had such significant anatomical changes to support their water-born lifestyle that they would only be taxonomically identifiable by genetic testing, which was indeed the way they were located in a clade with Artiodactyls in the 1990s.