# If Eagles Did Not Exist, Could Falcons Evolve Into Their Niche?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, anatomy

[This is related to the question as to whether or not cetaceans in an alternate Earth be related to a different group.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/could-whales-elsewhere-be-afrotheres)

The small but mercurial falcons belong to one order and one family--Falconiformes and Falconidae.  They catch and kill their prey with their beaks.

By contrast, the other group of raptors, Accipitriformes, consisting of hawks, eagles and Old World vultures, to name a few, catch and kill their prey with the claws on their feet.

Now let us imagine ourselves in an alternate Earth where Accipitriformes either:

a) became extinct
b) never existed.

In this sort of situation, we'd expect the falcons to evolve into a greater diversity of shapes, sizes and colors.

**Would falcons all still kill with their beaks, or would some of them evolve to fill the now-empty niche of the eagles and hawks and kill with their feet?**

Comment: Are you asking if falcons could be different, or are you asking whether humans might put them at a different point in the taxonomy.  Remember, the orders and families are there for *human* convenience.  They are based on how *we* want to order our world.

Comment: The former, yes.

Comment: The "should" in the title makes this look opinion-based. Consider "could" or "would" perhaps.

Comment: @Zxyrra  I don't see a "should".

Comment: It's the first word in the title.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit to clarify the question? The idea you present is fine but the delivery may not be ideal (looking at the downvote and closevote the Q just got)

Comment: @Zxyrra  Edit it how?

Comment: @JohnWDailey I'm thinking it may receive more positive attention if you put a bold sentence somewhat like this at the top of the question: "**If falcons never evolved, would other birds specialize to be like them?**"

Comment: @JohnWDailey I've edited your question to better clarify what I think you're asking (you're getting some close votes which I don't think are warranted). If that's not the case, feel free to revert it.

Comment: @Zxyrra and, of course, the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 7):

The extant dinosaurs, or *birds* as they are popularly called, form the clade [Neornithes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird) (a Greek compound which means "new birds"), corresponding to the classical class Aves (a Latin word which means "birds"). To the best of current knowledge, Neornithes is divided into two lineages:

- The [Palaeognathae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaeognathae) ("old jaws" in Greek): ostriches, emus, cassowaries, and kiwis. There are no palaeognath birds of prey; most palaeognath birds are flighless, and those few which can fly are very poor fliers.
- The [Neognathae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neognathae), the vast majority of the birds; the neognath birds are divided into two lineages:

  - The [Galloanserae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowl) (Latin for chickens-geese), or *fowl*; no birds of prey, although some of them are very good fliers.
  - The [Neoaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoaves) (a Greek-Latin compound meaning "new birds"). Within the bewildering diversity of the Neoaves there are many lineages, three of which are birds of prey:

    - The [Accipitrimorphae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accipitrimorphae) (which may be or not be the same thing as [Accipitriformes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accipitriformes)) ("accipiter" is a hawk or a falcon in Latin): the New World vultures, the eagles, and the hawks.
    - The [Strigiformes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl): the owls. ("Strix" is Latin for a [Screech owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screech_owl).)
    - The [Falconiformes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falconidae) or Falconidae ("falco" means falcon in Latin): the falcons.

The closest living relations of the falcons are the parrots, the sparrows and the song birds. The owls are not far from the eagles, vultures and hawks; both more closely related to woodpeckers than with falcons.

What is important is to notice that all [birds of prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_of_prey) conform to the stereotypical image of a bird as illustrated by a sparrow and show obvious similarities: they have "very good eyesight for finding food, strong feet for holding food, and a strong curved beak for tearing flesh" (from Wikipedia). In what degree these are inherited from the common ancestor of the [land birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telluraves) or represent [convergent evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution) is not yet known.

Since we already have three distinct lineages of birds of prey, we can deduce that this lifestyle provides a comfortable ecological niche. In a world with no Accipitriformes *something* would have taken their place; either the descendants of the Strigiformes, or the descendants of the Falconiformes, or even the descendants of some other group: but for sure the food would not be left uneaten; the prey would not be left unhunted.

There would still be falcons and hawks and eagles: only scientists will find out that they come from different lineages. After all, eagles and hawks had been classified in the same order Falconiformes as falcons for almost three centuries -- it was only recently that genetic studies showed that they were not closely related.

Comment: So what's your answer?  Would the eagle-falcons and hawk-falcons kill with their beaks or their claws?

Comment: @JohnWDailey: Convergent evolution will produce the archetypal bird of prey: exceptionally good flier with strong sharp claws and strong curved beak.

Comment: No, not all.  From Wikipedia:  "They differ from the eagles of Accipitridae, in that falcons kill with their beaks instead of their taloned feet. They have a "tooth" on the side of their beak for the purpose."

Comment: @JohnWDailey: That's a very minor detail, comparable to the difference in hunting styles between the great cats.

Comment: @JohnWDailey, their "niche" is where and what they kill, not how they kill it. The actual method of killing is a minor detail.