# Could Herons Be Related to Ducks Elsewhere?

Tags: biology, evolution, anatomy

[ [Set in the same alternate Earth as the afrotherian whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/could-whales-elsewhere-be-afrotheres)]

[image]

This provides the familiar image of Gastornis--a giant, flightless bird who hunted horses in the jungles of Eocene Europe.

But actually, recent evidence had given this image the 180.  Instead of eating meat, it was actually a gentle giant who ate leaves.

What's even more surprising is who its living relatives really are.

[image]

That's right.  Gastornis was, in reality, a giant, terrestrial anseriform bird.  **A land-based waterfowl.**  Which raises the question here.

[image]

Despite their similarities to storks or cranes, the heron is a member of Pelecaniformes, and the name alone would indicate who its closest relative is.  But we associate pelicans with longer, flappier bills, shorter legs with webbed feet and longer, broader wings.  The fact that both pelicans and herons belong to the same order despite the differences in appearance and niche means that in the scheme of classification, appearances shouldn't be taken for granted.

That said, in an alternate Earth, could the familiar heron image still be closest genetically to the anseriform birds--the ducks, geese, swans and screamers--or would I need to change its physical, superficial morphology to better fit its relation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to say the taxonomy is different, but they still look the same? OK, but why? What does that accomplish?

Comment: [Ichtyosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichthyosaur) are one of the best known examples of [convergent evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution). Yes, in a slightly different evolutionary history any niche can (and likely, would) be occupied by animals and plants descended from different ancestors. That's why biologists put more and more emphasis on DNA sequencing in order to determine the ancestry of species.

Comment: How similar are you talking about?  Humans share 50% of their DNA with bananas, 70% with worms, and 98% with pigs.  That's "close" (though highly misleading because of the big numbers involved, I admit).  But if you want to be able to say that just a 0.5% change to DNA makes a duck a stork, sure!  If you want them to be able to mate, that's another story.  Similarly, though we are "closely related" to chimpanzees, frankly a duck and stork seem closer than humans to chimpanzees from a distance to me (but I have human bias).  So what does "close" mean to you?

Comment: @GrinningX  Similar to this:  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/could-whales-elsewhere-be-afrotheres

Comment: Note that Gastornis wouldn't have eaten horses, but the Eocene ancestors of horses such as Eohippus, which was about the size of a small dog.

Answer (score 1):

There is no question on the Alternate earth you reference Heron and Ducks could be more closely related than they are on our own earth.

There are very minor changes in the family tree of both that could see them being quite close cousins.  I am stating this more from a generalist viewpoint than any specific study of avian evolutionary branchings.

I took a look at the 2 pictures giving family groupings for whales on earth and on the alternate - and there is no question you could pretty much put any avian species together with relatively little effort.

Answer (score 0):

### It's not Unreasonable... Depending on your Definition

This kind of question is very tricky, because you need to really specify exactly what you mean.  "Closest relative" is a tricky term, with some pairs of "closest relative" animals being separated by 100,000 years and others by a million year or more, depending largely on how many other relatives have died out.  Specific to this question, kill off all other "close" relatives of the duck and suddenly ducks and herons will be close living relatives (by default).  From a science-based perspective it is very helpful in these questions to state that you want two animals to be in the same Kingdom, Phylum, Order, Family, Genus or Species (and/or subgroups thereof).  It's far from perfect, but that ordering is the basis for understanding "closeness".

Next...

"Duck" is a bit of a broad term in the common lexicon.  No, seriously!  Let's look at two birds people would commonly call "ducks":

A Loon
[image: Yellow-billed Loon]

A Mallard
[image: Mallard]

Here's the thing though: the Loon is much more related to the Heron (by DNA) than the Mallard.  Mallards belong to a species that breaks with Heron's at the first demarcation point within the Aves class, while Loons share two claves within the Aves class with Herons (Ardeae & Aequornithes).

So maybe all we need to do is move the Heron from the Order Pelecaniformes to the Order Gaviiformes, which both share two claves within the Class "Aves" to meet your need?  That's probably easy enough to accomplish.  Herons share many physical traits with loons, and it is entirely conceivable that with the right environmental pressures a Heron could arise from that group.

**But there is a Catch**

It seems likely to me that if Herons were evolving in the Gaviiformes order they would be competing with early Storks if they share the same environment.  That means that either you would need to put Herons somewhere physically well separated from Storks and their descendants, or accept that the Ciconiiformes (Storks), Suliformes, and Pelecaniformes are going to lose species (eg. Ibis's may cease to exist).